# Does ajaxsetup error handler work for POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is going to sound like a weird question, but does the global error handler applied when using ajaxsetup get hit when there is an Ajax error on POST?

I have a few spots where I am trying to handle Ajax errors and none of them hit the error handler. The places that do hit the error handler are all GETs  and the places that do not are all POSTs, and I don't see any other reason why they wouldn't hit it.

It would be strange if it only worked for GET aside can't see any mention of this limitation in the jQuery docs.

Answer (score 0):

No, It works for both GET and POST. Looking at this documentation page (jQuery) http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, It show it should work irrespective of the request type.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what errors you are trying to catch and what ones you are catching, but I'll go with the idea that they aren't standard connection errors.

On that basis, when an error is caught by Ajax, it is normally a transport/connection issue.

For a `GET` request you may have:

- Page not found
- Timeout
- Not authorised
- Internal server error

and so on, all trying to get to the server or waiting for a response.

However, for a `POST` it is more of a fire and forget (it is not waiting for a reply). So the errors you would get would be along the lines of

- Page not found
- Timeout

because once the POST has been made, connects to the server, and gives its payload, the job has been done.

If you then have an issue, for example updating data (from an invalid Id or something similar), you need to send back a message that has a Status Code with it.

Then you can examine the status code returned and decide how you'd like to handle it.
Try sending back different error (or status) codes from the server and catching them client side:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET/POST',
        data: '...',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded, charset=UTF-8',
        timeout: 5000,
        beforeSend: myBeforeSendFunction,
        success: mySuccessFunction,
        error: myErrorFunction,
    statusCode: {
        500: function() {
        alert( "Oops! Server error here." );
        }
    }
});
```